# jasny fileupload element, not able to use it for edit operations

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, file-upload, jasny-bootstrap

Am trying to use fileupload from jasny-bootstrap for edit operation. There are certain pages where used is logged in, he/she already uploaded images and I want to be able to render them in order for user to change or remove.

am using the following

http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload

with following snippet

```
<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
  <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image" /></div>
  <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
  <div>
    <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" /></span>
    <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

it works perfectly on new images, but how can i render existing images? in the manual it says i must use fileupload-exists class instead of fileupload-new, which i tried and it shows the form in edit mode. but image from source is not displayed,  please advise

regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the image as preview (so in `.fileupload-preview`) and change the top class to `.fileupload-exists`.

```
<div class="fileupload fileupload-exists" data-provides="fileupload">
  <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&text=no+image" />
  </div>
  <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;">
     <img src="http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/assets/img/extended-by-jasny.png">
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select image</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" /></span>
    <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>​
```

Also check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GR2Lt/

*P.S. You currently have to click 'Remove' twice. This will be fixed in next version.*

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem for me. Can i get the double clicking for the remove button directly from the repository or is it not pushed yet?

Comment: Yes, you can use the WIP branch. https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/blob/2.2.2-j3-wip/js/bootstrap-fileupload.js

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I have a control that user cannot left blank "upload photo" field. And Even if I do this, I get "no file selected" error